# "GET /static/css%5Cmain.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Tags: python, html, css, flask

> I am making a web page with python and flask, but when I want to use css the console sends me this error and the changes in the html are not applied.  this is the .py file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
   return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/about")
def about():
   return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

> //this is the home.html file //

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
   scale=1.0">
  <title>Document with python</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 
     url_for('static',filename='css\main.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>hola mundo, como esta</h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

> //this is the main.css file //

```
body {
background: chartreuse;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
```

}

> edit: already change   css \ main.css   to    css / main.css

Comment: Change `css\main.css` to `css/main.css`

Comment: I already changed it, but it still doesn't work :(  this appeared  "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: and `main.css` is in `static/css/`?

Comment: sure, the main.css is in static / css

Comment: Can you confirm if main.css has read permission?

Comment: mmm I'm not sure if main.css has read permissions. could you explain me please?

Comment: What error message are you getting now? If it still has `%5C` in it, look for `*.pyc` files and delete them.

Comment: ls - l you can execute in shell inside /static/css for the permisisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 
 url_for('static',filename='css/main.css') }}">
```